# Prevent a sub-command from waiting forever for input from the user

Tags: bash, svn, input, exec, eval

I'm writing a simple deployment script for our code in bash. Currently I have some code like the following, which works fine normally. If for some reason the authentication fails (like the password gets changed but not changed in this script) then the `svn` command will ask for a password. As this is run through an automated system it will never be seen by someone.

How can I either make `svn` return a non-0 error code on authentication failure rather than just waiting forever (or as long as I've left it so far) for input?

The code snippet is:

```
if eval "svn update --username xxxxxxx --password xxxxxxx"; then
    echo "Updated from SVN ok"
else
    echo "Update from SVN failed"
    exit 1
fi

# Do more stuff here as update was ok
```

Obviously real username/password has been replaced with xxxxx.

If the password is wrong then this is what is output by the svn command:

```
Updating '.':
Authentication realm: <https://xxxxxxxxxxx:443> SVN
Username:
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Maybe you can concoct something using `expect` in which you are able to specify a timeout... http://oreilly.com/catalog/expect/chapter/ch03.html

Comment: Hi Mark, sounds like it is worth investigating. I'll have a look into it...

Comment: `eval` is unnecessary here; `if svn update ... ; then` is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `--non-interactive` option may be what you're looking for.

From the output of `svn help update`:

```
Global options:
  <skipped a few items here>
  --non-interactive       : do no interactive prompting
```

I'm not 100% sure, but it sounds like with this option, if a password authentication is required, svn will just fail with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: That looks like it might be a good bet.  I missed that when scanning the help page. +1

Comment: I also missed this when looking at the help page! Thanks guys for your help, we had some good ideas from @Mark Setchell and DigitalTrauma which I'm sure I'll use in future applications, but this has to be the accepted answer because it's the simplest and most reliable/upgrade-proof. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `eval` is unnecessary (and usually discouraged for security reasons).

I don't know `svn` well, but its worth trying the `--quiet` or `--force` options to see if it will prevent re-asking for username/password:

```
if svn update --force --username xxxxxxx --password xxxxxxx; then
```

or

```
if svn update --quiet --username xxxxxxx --password xxxxxxx; then
```

Failing that, if you have a recent version of GNU coreutils (I'm assuming your on [linux](/questions/tagged/linux)), then you can use the timeout command:

```
timeout 5 svn update --username xxxxxxx --password xxxxxxx
if (( $? != 124 )); then
    echo "Updated from SVN ok"
else
    echo "Update from SVN timed out after 5 seconds"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried after your suggestion the `--force` and `--quite` options but neither help here unfortunately. I appreciate the time on `eval`. Regarding the timeout idea, sounds good, but sometime there might be a big update to happen, can you have a timeout after no output from the command for a certain amount of time? If that makes sense?

Comment: @LukeCousins - understood.  Then as Mark suggests, `expect` is probably your best bet.

Comment: But wait - I see you're the Technical Director.  You can make the call to switch to decent version control, such as [tag:git], instead of clunky `svn` ;-)

Comment: Haha, we're thinking of switching to git, but haven't quite managed as we've so many things working with it right now! We're also going to be using Phing, Capistrano or similar soon, but this is more of a quick solution to tide us over :-)

Comment: Thanks the upvote!  In hindsight this is a crumby answer and I was about to delete it, but I guess its worth leaving up for the `timeout` info.

Comment: Yeah, the timeout bit will be helpful to me in the future and others I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

For tools which lack a command line option, you can redirect standard input, so they don't actually try to read from a (blocking) console:

```
svn </dev/null update --username xxxxxxx --password xxxxxxx
```